# Override key values in hybris map editor

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

Is it possible to override the key values that are being populated for a map type attribute of an itemtype in backoffice? I've found the default MAP editor and spent almost 2hours debugging the application to see how the key values are populated but I couldn't find anything. For example, I want to display only 3 out of 5 enum values based on some logic when a new map entry is created.

[image]

Comment: Please try to extend DefaultEditorAreaLogicHandler and override beforeEditorAreaRender method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two options.

1. You can create a custom editor to extends the map editor https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/8bd4c25286691014b3f9876ca5816926.html
2. You can define a new itemType to store your pair key-values and use the Default Multi Reference Editor https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/8bad002786691014924ba694583a1368.html to configure search options